# React Single Page app with browserHistory possible?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I've been building a react single page app using `hashHistory` from `react-router`, and things have been working fine until I decided to remove the trailing code in the URL that looks like this: `#/?_k=ncbx6v`.

The recommended solution I came across was to transition to browserHistory, but I noticed all the examples and solutions require using `webpack-dev-server` with `history-api-fallback` set to true. I tried this approach and it worked (going through `localhost`), but the standalone bundle.js file + index.html that once worked no longer works.

When I run webpack and open the html file, I get this error in the console:
`Warning: [react-router] Location "/Users/mike/project/index.html" did not match any routes`

I am not familiar with the mechanics behind the issue, but I'm curious if there's a solution out there I'm not familiar with.

This is my webpack file:

```
const {resolve} = require('path')

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    context: resolve('src'),
    entry: './app',
    output: {
      path: resolve('public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      publicPath: '/public/'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
    },
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      reasons: true,
      chunks: false
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {enforce: 'pre', test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'eslint-loader', exclude: [/node_modules/]},
        {test: /\.jsx?$/,loader: 'babel-loader', include: /src/, exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
        {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
        {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file-loader"},
        {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: "url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000"},
        {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"},
        {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my app.js:

```
'use strict'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Layout from './components/common/Layout'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

const store = configureStore()

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path='/' component={Layout}></Route>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the browser history, you will need a backend that can handle routing for all of your possible routes. If you do not plan on having a backend that can support routing (e.g., you will be serving static files) you should stick to the hash history.

The basic explanation of how browser history works is that it looks at the `pathname` of the current URL and attempts to match that against the known routes. In your included error, your `pathname` is `/Users/mike/project/index.html`. That means that in order for React Router to match that URL, you would have to have defined the `<Route>`'s `path` (or have a series of nested `<Route>`s) to be `/Users/mike/project/index.html`.

```
<Route path='Users/mike/project/index.html' component={App} />
```

The hash history works with static files because it just appends a hash symbol after the `pathname` and determines the route by what falls after that.

If your issue is just that you do not like having the query key (the `?_k=jkadjlkd`), you can specify that that should not be included when you [create your `history` instance](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#using-custom-histories). The URLs will still include the `#`, but no longer have the key "junk" attached to them.

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'

const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })
<Router history={appHistory} />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I also want to point out for other users that this only works with history@2.1.2 or lower. I initially installed the latest version of history only to end up with a blank page being rendered.

Comment: Which version of `history` were you using before? Looking at the changelog https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/v3.2.1/CHANGES.md#300-0 it appears that with v3 the `hashHistory` should not include the query key by default. v4 does not work because it was rewritten for use with the upcoming v4 of React Router.

Comment: It was indeed v4 that was installed by default. I just tested v3 and removing the `querykey: false`, but I'm getting a new error in the console: `bundle.js:578 Uncaught Error: You have provided a history object created with history v3.x. This version of React Router is not compatible with v3 history objects. Please use history v2.x instead.`

Seems like I should stick with 2?

Note I'm using react-router@2.0.0

Comment: You can stick with v2 if you'd like, but v3 of React Router is compatible with v2 (it just removed deprecated code from v1), so using RR v3 _should_ be an easy upgrade.

Comment: Gotcha, I will check it out. Thanks a lot!